# Cannot get data from firebase with filter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with firebase, so don't be very strict...
I have next database:

```
{"list":[
          {
             "id":0,
             "name":"name",
             "text":"text"
          },
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"name",
             "text":"text"
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "name":"name",
             "text":"text"
          },
          {
             "id":3,
             "name":"name",
             "text":"text"
          }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Here is my code for request:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Query mQuery = database.getReference("list")
                .child("id").startAt("2");
mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

but this request return null...

Will be glad any idea?

**UPDATE**

I need to get all items where id is bigger than asked one.

Comment: i think the database structure you shown does not looks like a firebase database. **It looks like a response of some API call**. Actually Firebase database have a unique ID for each node entered i don't see anything similar to that in your database.

Comment: take a look on screen from database site

Comment: Use _ChildEventListener_ which will give you value of your node one by one

Comment: I told you you are using wrong listener to get data

Comment: @PiyushGupta, no, i am using correct listener! here is correct answer for my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38240508/4488594

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an order-by method

```
Query mQuery = database.getReference("list")
            .orderByChild("id").startAt(2);
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Query mQuery = database.getReference("list")
>             .child("id").startAt("2");
> ```

This query returns nodes at `https://<YOUR_FIREBASE_APP>.firebaseio.com/list/id` which doesn't exist and so you get a null result.

Try this instead

```
Query mQuery = database.getReference("list").startAt("2");
```